# Searching for cause of scrolling causing repainting and bad performance

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

https://fornida.herokuapp.com/

This site is in dev and I am troubleshooting an issue that causes "scroll updates" to recalculate styles and repaint. On the frontend it is janky and very bad.

This screenshot is a recording using Google’s performance

[image]

[Reducing scroll jank when using overflow-y: scroll;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261456/reducing-scroll-jank-when-using-overflow-y-scroll)

I’ve read several other posts but none of them seem to apply. This may be an Angular 5 task but I don’t know.

I am looking for help pin-pointing what is causing scroll performance issues. Using the link above, does anything stand out?

Comment: post your code here, edit the question and add it there

Comment: I dont know what code is causing the issue... ?